# Salsa 20 C++ Text Encryption

Tags: c++, encryption, text

I want to make Salsa20 Text Encryption using C++
I took [this source code](https://github.com/everard/Salsa20) as main

How to initialize iv and key? How to encrypt bytes?

Comment: And be careful when using other peoples code, don't fall into the trap of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). The best way to learn a subject is to do it yourself, not copying someone elses solution and attempting to make it work as your own (legal copyright problem aside, if you don't understand what the code does or how it works you can never truly use it).